# How to convert address (as text) to gps coordinates?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, openstreetmap

Let's say I have address as text:

> 901 Cherry Ave. San Bruno, CA 94066 USA

is there any FREE service, which can help me to identify GPS coordinates (longitude and latitude) of this address? (I'll use that in my application, so it should be some kind of API)

The text can be in any language.

Comment: Thanks for google API links (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/). Is there the same functionality for OSM?

Comment: Here is the link for OSM geocoding - http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The process is called of converting address to geographic coordinates is called *geocoding*.

Depending on how you'll be using the data, there's an API available from Google, details [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Geocoding). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, using _geocoding_ word I've found OSM API.

Answer (score 3):

It really doesn't mather which framework you use, cause if you want something big you can have a big surprise: a limit of 2.5 K request /day this in case you don't store those info in a xml for later use.
So at this moment you can find a better way to combine this with a OSM feature for localization.

Answer (score 2):

check this google map api 3 service this is the reverse-geocoding service in google map api

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Geocoding

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2010/03/introducing-new-google-geocoding-web.html

Comment: Thanks. Is there the same functionality for OSM?

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code I use. I've prepared it basing on voncox code (thanks). Just didn't want to use Zend.
If you need to geocode multiple addresses just close this code with any kind of loop but probably there is faster way. I've used it only for about 100 addresses and it took about 30 seconds to process.

```
$street="Lwowska 4"; $postcode="00-658"; $city="Warszawa"; $region="mazowieckie";

$a=$street.", ".$postcode.", ".$city.", ".$region;
$address = urlencode($a);
$link = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=".$address."&sensor=false";
$file = file_get_contents($link);

if(!$file)  {
  echo "Err: No access to Google service: ".$a."<br/>\n";
}else {
  $get = simplexml_load_string($file);

  if ($get->status == "OK") {
      $lat = (float) $get->result->geometry->location->lat;
      $long = (float) $get->result->geometry->location->lng;
      echo "lat: ".$lat."; long: ".$long."; ".$a."<br/>\n";
  }else{
    echo "Err: address not found: ".$a."<br/>\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, Marcin. It might be a good idea to remove the MySQL parts of your answer, as it's not relevant to the question, and could cause some confusion.

Comment: Well done.  I *only* needed address-to-GPS conversion and wasted huge amounts of time on Google's site trying to get an API key, permission it to an API, testing it... etc.  This approach doesn't require a key and simply provides data back.  It's all I really needed in the first place, not an embedded map.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able/willing to use php and Zend Framework then most of the Google Maps API is abstracted by using Zend_Http_Client.

For example:

```php
$address = '69 Some Road, Somewhere, NW1 8UJ';

$http = new Zend_Http_Client('google_maps_url');
$http->setParameterGet(array('address' => $address, 'sensor' => 'false'));
$get = $http->request();
$get = json_decode($get->getBody());

if ($get->status == self::GOOGLE_MAPS_SUCCESS) {
    $lat = (float) $get->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
    $long = (float) $get->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, MapQuest's Community License has an 'open' api, which uses nominatim / OpenStreetMap on the backside.

It is the same API (interface-wise) as the Community 'Licensed' api, which makes it easy to transition later.

I found that the open version requires the address to be a little too exact; on the first day after deployment we "missed" several addresses. We thought the service was down, but it turns out the street names were missing little details such as a direction (ex SW).

Tried out the Licensed version, and it returned even the misspelled addresses.

The Community license licensed data version is free also, but are restricted by pretty much the same terms as the Google one.  The 'open' data you can do with what you want.

If you are going to end up paying, then Yahoo's Boss/Geo api seems to be the cheapest for low volume; they just don't have a free version.