# how to get coordinates from street address

Tags: c#, location, windows-phone-8

I'm working on windows phone 8 app, but i can't find, how to get coordinates form address. 
Problem is, i have my coordiantes, and i need to calculate distance between me and some address.

windows phone 8 is not documented that much, so please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert address (as text) to gps coordinates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996577/how-to-convert-address-as-text-to-gps-coordinates)

Comment: Umm in that topic, was anwser in other language, not in c#, and many codes work on wp7.5 and not on wp8.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're looking for is called "geocoding": Converting an address to GeoCoordinate.

As was mentioned before you can use Google and Bing on WP7 to achieve that. On windows phone 8 Geocoding and Reverse Geocoding are supported as part of the framework. You can read an overview to GeoCoding [at this Nokia intro article](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/What%27s_new_in_Windows_Phone_8#Maps) (under "Geocoding") and a more comprehensive overview [at this other Nokia article](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!guide-to-the-maps.html;#toc_Searchingforanaddress).

Here's an example of Geocoding converting from an address to coordinates:

```
private void Maps_GeoCoding(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    GeocodeQuery query = new GeocodeQuery()
    {
        GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(0, 0),
        SearchTerm = "Ferry Building, San-Francisco"
    };
     query.QueryCompleted += query_QueryCompleted;
    query.QueryAsync();
}

void query_QueryCompleted(object sender, QueryCompletedEventArgs<IList<MapLocation>> e)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine("Ferry Building Geocoding results...");
    foreach (var item in e.Result)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(item.GeoCoordinate.ToString());
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Name);
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Description);
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Address.BuildingFloor);
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Address.BuildingName);
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Address.BuildingRoom);
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Address.BuildingZone);
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Address.City);
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Address.Continent);
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Address.Country);
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Address.CountryCode);
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Address.County);
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Address.District);
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Address.HouseNumber);
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Address.Neighborhood);
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Address.PostalCode);
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Address.Province);
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Address.State);
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Address.StateCode);
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Address.Street);
        sb.AppendLine(item.Information.Address.Township);
    }
    MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
}
```

When I run this code snippet on my WP8 I get the following messagebox:

[image: MEssageBox showing details for the ferry building]

Answer (score 0):

You have several options, the one i have use to accomplish this is using a web service, GOOGLE, BING, YAHOO ect.

on Bing (Cus is for windows phone)
you need a key to access the maps api You can get the key at
http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers/mobile.aspx

once you have the key you can accese the WP7.1 SDK for BING or if that dont work for you, use the location api on the Rest Service
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701715.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Bing Maps REST services also provides functionality to get Lat/Long from a given address, more info can be found on the [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701714.aspx)

You will need to get a Bind Maps key though [here...](http://www.bingmapsportal.com/)