# How can I retrieve the coordinates of a specific object in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, bing-maps

I have the name of the street or another object. How to get its geo coordinates using the built in map functionality of Windows Phone 8.1. (I guess its Bing maps)

Comment: Very vague. What did you try to do and what is your problem with actual code?

Comment: I don't know what code to begin with. How to guess classes names that I don't even know they exist?

Comment: Did you give a try to that answer ? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23728074/how-do-i-get-geolocation-of-a-street-address-in-windows-phone-8-1-universal-app

Comment: I don't have a Hint location to provide, since I don't know anything but the name of my location? I don't know the city its in or even the country. I don't think this FindLocationsAsync will help me anyways. Any other suggestions?