# Google maps on windows phone 8

Tags: c#, google-maps, windows-phone-8

I am have Create a map control in xaml using Windows Phone toolkit. I wanted to search some address on map, Like user will enter the Address in TextBox then I have to find that Address on the Map. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have two things you want to do.
1) Find geo coordinates based on the address.
2) Use the coordinates to show a pin on the Map control.

For #1, you can check out JustinAngel's answer here as to how you can find geo coordinates from an address.

[how to get coordinates from street address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14457247/how-to-get-coordinates-from-street-address)

For #2, once you have the coordinates, you can follow something like this blog to add the map control to the WP8 app and eventually add a pin at the required address/coordinates

[Maps in Windows Phone 8 and Phone toolkit](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/maps-in-windows-phone-8-and-phone-toolkit-a-winning-team-part-1/)

or

[Customized PushPin without WP8 toolkit PushPin Control](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Customized_PushPin_without_WP8_toolkit_PushPin_Control)